# Saving local variables for an unpredictable broken function in R

Tags: r, debugging, local-variables

My question is about debugging. Sometimes a function of my script would crash when I feed it with irregular input data and I want to find out how it crashed and then fix it (the workspace is always discarded because I usually run a batch of tasks and the workspace is very large). The error messages are helpful but not always enough for identifying the real problem. I know that we can always re-run the code and check the variables that might be related and then debug it. But the problem here is my script usually takes hours or longer to reach the crashing point (it has passed unit test and works well on regular data for thousands of times). So, I am wondering if there is a way that I can save the workspace only when the error occurs, then I can just load the workspace and check the issue.

I have learnt that *options(error = dump.frames)* might be helpful but it only saves the global variables and my errors usually happens in functions and the local variables cannot be captured. (it is not completely useless because I can run a loop manually from the global variables in the workspace. But my code structure is quite complicated and it would be a bit painful)
Another idea is to output the variables in the function every time it is used. But it is not feasible because some functions would be used very frequently and the variables can be of large size. Frequently outputting these variables would be super slow.
I hope I can get some advice here on how people usually debug code like this. Thank you!

Response to the comments:

1. I am working on Linux. Usually it would not kill the R session. Yes, I am running in terminal.

Comment: On windows, mac or linux? And when it irregularly crashes, does it kill your R session? And are you running in terminal...?